# In FullCalendar can I get behaviour similar to droppable without using dragging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Full Calendar has an option to [allow dragging of external jQuery UI draggables onto the calendar](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/droppable/). As you can see on this [demo](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.4.0/demos/external-dragging.html) (most evident on the "week" view), as you drag an event over timeslots the relevant timeslots are highlighted depending on the duration of the event that will be created. The droppable events will also conform to any [constraints](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventConstraint/) that are specified for them. This means that when dragging over invalid timeslots they are not highlighted, and the drop will not be accepted.

Is it possible to get these features without actually using draggables? I would like to place a pre-specified event (title, duration) onto the calendar, with automatic constraint calculation and the visual feedback described above, but with simple mousover and click.

---

Tobclarify I want to click on a timeslot to create an event of a predetermined duration starting in the chosen timeslot. I only want the event to be created if it is within a set of constraints. I also want to visually communicate on mouseover which time range will be covered by an event if I click.

Comment: Need a bit more clarity on this. Not sure how a "specified event on the calendar" is supposes to change this. But FullCalendar has hover events, that you could use to indicate which area to highlight.

Comment: When an event has a duration that is different from that of your timeslots you are not selecting a single timeslot but a set. The drag and drop UI conveys which set of timeslots you are trying to select as you hover. It also does the calculations to determine if the timeslot set is within the constraints. I want that level of feedback while mousing over and/or the automatic constraint calculation.

Comment: If you are just mousing over, wouldn't that just be over one slot, so you would not have to worry about selecting neighboring time slots? Also if you are just mousing over why would there be any constraints?

Comment: @jjbskir, I am mousing over in order to create an event that spans multiple timeslots. Try the demo that is linked and see the edit to the question.

Comment: Is this an idea? Trigger the mousedown programmatically on the predefined event and hide the cloned object that will follow the cursor. This way the user doesn’t have to click and drag anything but it is simulated in the background. Trigger mouseup when the user clicks on the calendar.

Comment: @jaz, sounds plausible. Throw it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that I consider *very hacky*. **Please improve this answer.**

### Prerequisites

- FullCalendar,
- jQuery UI with `draggable`,
- this "simulations" [testing utils plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/9e8e339648901899827a58e5bf919f7dda03b88e/tests/jquery.simulate.js) from jQuery

### Approach

Every time a drag might be interrupted:

1. create an element with an associated event,
2. make it draggable,
3. simulate a `mousedown` event.

There is a working version at http://jsfiddle.net/u863kysr/2/

```
// My Predetermined Event
var potentialEvent = {
    duration: '1:30:00',
    title: 'Your Bookiing',
    constraint: 'businessHours',
};

// Create the FullCalendar
$cal = $('#cal').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    businessHours: true,
    droppable: true,
    allDaySlot: false,
})

var $draggable = null;
// Mouseup definitely stops dragging.
$(document.body).on('mouseup', function () {
    if ($draggable) {
        $draggable.remove()
    }

    // Create a new element so that it's positioned at {clientX: 0, clientY: 0}.
    $draggable = $('<div></div>')
        .css('position', 'fixed')
        .css('top', 0)
        .css('left', 0)
        .insertBefore($cal);

    // Associate the event with the element in the way theat FullCalendar expects.
    $draggable
        .data('event', potentialEvent)
        .draggable();

    // After this event has finished, simulate a mousedown so that it acts like
    // it is being dragged.
    setTimeout(function () {
        $draggable.simulate('mousedown', {
            clientX: 0,
            clientY: 0
        });
    }, 0)
}).trigger('mouseup');
```

### Limitations

It doesn't handle scrolling of the FullCalendar. The drop location becomes offset from the mouse by the amount scrolled.